# How can I get the distinct count in dataframe in python

Tags: python

I am confused that how can i get a distinct result when i am using pandas.groupby:

```
import pandas
data = {'Period':['2016-02','2016-02','2016-02','2016-02','2016-03','2016-03'],
        'Name':['a','b','c','c','d','e']}
data = pandas.DataFrame(data)
print(data.groupby('Period')['Name'].count())
```

i want to get the same result like sql does:

```
select Period,count(distinct Name) from data group by 1
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
data.groupby('Period')['Name'].nunique()
```

'Count' counts occurrences (dis-including Nulls), 'nunique' gives the N of uniques.

Comment: Oh! Yes. that is exactly what i want. thank you very much! And i am curious if i can check this in some sort of manual  or document? and where can i get this manual  or document about 'groupby' or 'pandas'?